# How to run a php api file from another php api file after a certain delay, and without using sleep()?

Tags: php, api, web-services

I have two restful api endpoints; **DispatchJob_Public.php** and **selectDriverForJobResult.php** and I have to call **selectDriverForJobResult.php** from **DispatchJob_Public.php** after **two minutes**. How can i do that **without** using **sleep()**? Because i cannot afford putting server on busy wait (due to sleep function).

I have written a function in javascript and ajax to call the second file **(selectDriverForJobResult.php)**, and that works fine when i hit the end point directly from browser but js **doesnt work** when the file is called from **android or postman**.

So i need a solution for this, that *does not include* **cron job**, **javascript** and **sleep()** function.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you explain why a `two minutes` gap?

Comment: Also, if you don't need `cron job` solution, remove the tags from your question.

Comment: @vivek_23 because the second file will collect the data about the drivers who will bid in those two seconds. So need a two minute gap.

Comment: The only best practice option I see for you here would be to implement a queue system, which actually would depend on a cronjob running them for you. Having a cronjob constantly running a file, and checking a database table if there are any queued jobs that needs to be run. 

Only other option is if you are running php as PHP-FPM, not an apache module. Then you can read more about: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php

Comment: @OleHaugset queue is acceptable but cronjob cant help me here. Thing is that how would i pass parameters to cronjob for checking whether two minutes are complete or not? Secondly I am running php as CGI/FastCGI. But i am unable to run the function fastcgi_finish_request(). Can you recommend me some detailed documentation of this function?

Answer (score 0):

directly from php, there is no way

you can write a bash file and execute it with system

startBatch.sh

```
 sleep 2m
 php /path/fo/file.php
```

in your first file

```
system('./startBatch.sh >> null');
```

Comment: If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

Comment: Yes @OleHaugset that is right, and i cannot use sleep because if there was lets say 100 requests in one minute? The system will fail to handle any of them if i used sleep.

Comment: @OleHaugset fixed it